# Power BI - 1 chart works, 1 chart doesn't work...but they're the same chart

Tags: matrix, charts, powerbi

I work for a retailer with multiple banners. I made a BI report for all these banners by copying the first banner's slide multiple times and changing the filter.

Everything worked fine for many months, but now the 'Avg Store Size' column works on the first banner, but not the others. But they are the exact same chart, puling from the exact same data, but with different filters.

[image: Working chart]

[image: Not working chart]

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Mark

Comment: Update: It has something to do with my date table. When I take off the date filter, it works fine. That said, the date filter works for my first banner. So frustrating.

Comment: Do you check you have data for the second banner for the selected date?

Comment: I just checked, and changed the date filter from a macro level Fiscal year filter to a per week filter and it did the job. Thanks!